# "argument[] calldata" type encoding in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to encode calldata for the following solidity function with `abi.encodeWithSelector`:

```
function someFunction(
    uint a,
    uint b,
    address[] calldata c,
    address d,
    uint e
)
```

My code sample:

```
bytes out = abi.encodeWithSelector(
      bytes4(keccak256(bytes("someFunction(uint,uint,address[],address,uint)"))),
      a,
      b,
      ["0xAddr1Here", "0xAddr2Here"],
      "0xAddr3Here",
      e
    )
```

When I try to call it with `addr.call(out)`, it doesn't work (I have debug `console.log()` on the first line of `someFunction` and there is no debug message in my terminal).
I'm sure that the problem is in `address[] calldata` argument. How to encode it correctly?
I know, that it's possible to change `calldata` to `memory` and I know how to encode `address[] memory`, but I can't do it - target function is not in my project, it's some external function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uint` is an alias for `uint256`.

The function selector is generated from the full type names (`uint256`) - not their aliases (`uint`).

```
bytes4(keccak256(bytes("someFunction(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)")))
```